# to calculate the distribution of m*(A+B)^2+n*abs(A-B)

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, sum

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are two independent random variables both following a normal distribution with a zero mean and a variance $\sigma^2$. How to calculate the distribution of $m \cdot (A+B)^2+n \cdot \mathrm{abs}(A-B)$ ($m,n$ are constant)?